# Notification Network error

Tags: networking, network-manager, notification

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. Initially there is nothing strange, after I observed the notification network in Ubuntu always just showed up and said that my computer is not connected to the Internet, even though I already connected and can access the internet.

Every 10 minutes or more notifications that always appear and then disappear, and it was very disturbing, especially when I'm watching a movie.

[image: Notification Network error]

Answer (score 0):

With Xubuntu you just have to right click on your network manager icon located in the top bar and than you disable "Enable Notifications":
[image]

Comment: I use unity and unfortunately I could not find such an option, btw thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

**OP's answer**

Install `dconf-editor`, after installing open `dconf-editor` and scroll down to org ▸ gnome ▸ nm-applet and checklist `disable-connected-notifications` and `disable-disconnected-notifications`.